# Is there a GraphQL type for multiple specific strings?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I am trying to create a GraphQL Type which the key should accept either 'UP', 'DOWN', 'LEFT' or 'RIGHT', and instead of utilising `key: String`, I wish I could define similarly to TypeScript, such as `key: 'UP' | 'DOWN' | 'LEFT' | 'RIGHT'`.

Is that possible and how do I achieve that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

graphql also supports enum types: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#enumeration-types

```
enum key {
  UP
  DOWN
  LEFT
  RIGHT
}
```